# How can I do automation for excel to xml in python?

Tags: python, xml, linux, excel, python-2.7

My question is that I have assigned one task in that I have to read excel document and store that data into XML file. So I have done one code in python for that. But it giving me error when I am writing an XML file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xlrd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('anuja.xls')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('anuja.xlsx', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # Header
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
# tronsform the workbook to a list of dictionnaries
data =[]
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)

for set1 in data :
    f = open('data.xml', 'w')
    f.write("<Progress>%s</Progress>" % (set1[0]))
    f.write("<P>%s</P>" % (set1[1]))
    f.write("<Major>%s</Major>" % (set1[2]))
    f.write("<pop>%s</pop>" % (set1[3]))
    f.write("<Key>%s</Key>" % (set1[4]))
    f.write("<Summary>%s</Summary>" % (set1[5]))
```

**Error is**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./read.py", line 23, in <module>
    f.write("<Progress>%s</Progress>" % (set1[0]))
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Test for Empty lines before your write.

Comment: You should provide some sample excel contents.

Comment: @AdamOwczarczyk how to attach file will you please tell me i am new user to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

So the error message actually tells you that there is no key '0' that you try to write to the XML file.

Some more Tipps:

1. You open the XML file in every iteration of your loop which will fail
2. There are easier ways to create XML files, check out this article https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/write-xml-to-file/
3. You should check out a python debugger, it will make it easy for you to investigate e.g. what your data loop looks from the inside. I like ipdb most https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will follow your tipps

Comment: Thanks for your help that XML link is really helpful for me.my problem is resolved now.